# Grafana Github authentication - Github returns empty team list

Tags: github, oauth, grafana

I'm trying to configure Grafana to authenticate using Github, but only for members of a certain team. I've configured the [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/github/), but Github returns an empty list when Grafana tries to fetch the users teams.

```
logger=oauth.github t=2022-05-22T13:23:16.6+0000 lvl=dbug msg="HTTP GET" url="https://api.github.com/user/teams?per_page=100" status="200 OK" response_body=[]
```

I've configured Grafana to use the `user:email,read:org` scopes according to the documentation.

I figured I might have to add some permissions to the GitHub app I created, but [I can't find any permission](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-github-apps#metadata-permissions) that grants access to the `user/teams` endpoint requested by Grafana.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out...

I had created a GitHub App, not a GitHub **OAuth** App.

The devil is in the details